# Unable to add an app in SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

The app is already in the corporate store but while adding the app it gives error

> You can't add this app here.. for details "Ask your administrator to turn on Web Site Autohosting"
>
> Details Description : There is no description available.
> Supported Languages : Supported languages are not specified.

If anyone can let me know how to enable Website auto hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is resolved by enabling preview feature from office 365 admin setting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I came a cross similar situation and the solution was to make sure the publishing features are enabled in the app catalog site collection. In case someone comes across this and the above solution doesn't help.